# Preset Variable with Pickle

Tags: python, pickle

```
    import time
    from random import randint
    import pickle

    MaTC = 1
    MaTC = pickle.dump(MaTC, open("MaTCFile.txt", "wb"))

    AnTC = 2
    AnTC = pickle.dump(AnTC, open("AnTCFile.txt", "wb"))

    AuTC = 3
    AuTC = pickle.dump(AuTC, open("AuTCFile.txt", "wb"))

    AlTC = 3
    AlTC = pickle.dump(AlTC, open("AlTCFile.txt", "wb"))

    JaTC = 3
    JaTC = pickle.dump(JaTC, open("JaTCFile.txt", "wb"))

    print("Hello Jacob")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Choose an option!")
    print("(1) Selecting Cleaners")
    print("(2) Edit Cleaning Information")
    print("(3) Reserved")
    MenuChoice = input(": ")
    if MenuChoice == "1":
        print("Selecting Cleaner Function")

    elif MenuChoice == "2":
        print("(1) Check cleaning info")
        print("(2) Enter New Cleaning info")
        InfoSelect = input(": ")
            if InfoSelect == "2":

            Mare = { "Mares Times Cleaned": MaTC}
            Andre = { "Andres Times Cleaned": AnTC}
            Al = { "Als Times Cleaned": AlTC}
            Austin = { "Austins Times Cleaned": AuTC}
            Jacob = { "Jacobs Times Cleaned": JaTC}
            pickle.dump( Mare, open ("MaresFile.txt", "wb"))
            pickle.dump( Jacob, open ("JacobsFile.txt", "wb"))
            pickle.dump( Andre, open ("AndresFile.txt", "wb"))
            pickle.dump( Austin,open ("AustinsFile.txt", "wb"))
            pickle.dump( Al, open ("AlsFile.txt", "wb"))
            print(Mare)
            print(Austin)
            print(Jacob)
            print(Andre)
            print(Al)
```

Okay so basically what I am trying to achieve is have the MaTC, AnTC, AuTC, AlTC, and JaTC Variables be preset as 1, 2, 3, 3, and 3 at the first time running the program. But when I want to add 2 to say MaTC making it 3, When I start the program again I want it to = 3 on startup. I just started python a few days ago, I would love the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use exceptions to handle the case where the file does not exist (i.e. first run of the program)

```
try:
  f = open("MaTCFile.dat", "rb") # Pickle is not a .txt format
  MaTC = pickle.load(f)
except IOError:
  # Initialise default value
  MaTC = 1
```

I would also be inclined to store all the variables in a single file using a dict:

```
default_data = {
  "MaTC": 1, "AnTC": 2, # ... etc.
```

as this would make the program more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a refactored version of your program. It uses the `pickle` module and demonstrates usage of `pickletools`, `zlib`, and a few other module. Hopefully, the code will help you further along in writing your program. One subject that you probably will want to research in the future is that of databases.

```
import os
import pickle
import pickletools
import sys
import zlib


SETTINGS_FILE = 'settings.sav'


def main():
    """Present the user with a cleaning application."""
    settings = load_settings(SETTINGS_FILE)
    print('Hello, Jacob!')
    while True:
        if show_menu(settings,
                     select_cleaners,
                     edit_cleaning_information,
                     reserved,
                     close_program):
            break
    settings.save(SETTINGS_FILE)


def load_settings(path):
    """Create the settings schema and load them from file is possible."""
    settings = Namespace(mares=Parameter(1, is_positive_int),
                         andres=Parameter(2, is_positive_int),
                         austin=Parameter(3, is_positive_int),
                         al=Parameter(3, is_positive_int),
                         jacob=Parameter(3, is_positive_int))
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        settings.load(path)
    return settings


def is_positive_int(value):
    """Ensure that the value is valid for the settings."""
    return isinstance(value, int) and value >= 0


def show_menu(context, *args):
    """Help display a menu to the user."""
    for option, function in enumerate(args, 1):
        print(option, '-', function.__doc__)
    while True:
        number = get_int('Please enter an option: ') - 1
        if 0 <= number < len(args):
            return args[number](context)
        else:
            print('Your number was out of range.')


def get_int(prompt):
    """Get a valid number from the user."""
    while True:
        try:
            text = input(prompt)
        except EOFError:
            sys.exit()
        else:
            try:
                return int(text)
            except ValueError:
                print('You did not enter an integer.')


def select_cleaners(context):
    """Choose this to select your cleaner."""
    print('Selecting Cleaning Function')


def edit_cleaning_information(context):
    """You can edit the cleaning information."""
    show_menu(context, check_cleaning_info, enter_new_cleaning_info)


def reserved(context):
    """This is reserved for future use."""
    print('NOT AVAILABLE')


def close_program(context):
    """Close the program."""
    return True


def check_cleaning_info(context):
    """Show all cleaning info."""
    print('Mares:', context.mares)
    print('Andres:', context.andres)
    print('Austin:', context.austin)
    print('Al:', context.al)
    print('Jacob:', context.jacob)


def enter_new_cleaning_info(context):
    """Enter in additional cleaning information."""
    while True:
        name = input('Who needs cleaning info adjusted? ').capitalize()
        if name == 'Mares':
            context.mares += get_int('Add to Mares: ')
        elif name == 'Andres':
            context.andres += get_int('Add to Andres: ')
        elif name == 'Austin':
            context.austin += get_int('Add to Austin: ')
        elif name == 'Al':
            context.al += get_int('Add to Al: ')
        elif name == 'Jacob':
            context.jacob += get_int('Add to Jacob: ')
        else:
            continue
        break

###############################################################################


class _Settings:

    """_Settings(*args, **kwargs) -> _Settings instance"""

    @staticmethod
    def _save(path, obj):
        """Save an object to the specified path."""
        data = zlib.compress(pickletools.optimize(pickle.dumps(obj)), 9)
        with open(path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(data)

    @staticmethod
    def _load(path):
        """Load an object from the specified path."""
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            data = file.read()
        return pickle.loads(zlib.decompress(data))


class Namespace(_Settings):

    """Namespace(**schema) -> Namespace instance"""

    def __init__(self, **schema):
        """Initialize the Namespace instance with a schema definition."""
        self.__original, self.__dynamic, self.__static, self.__owner = \
            {}, {}, {}, None
        for name, value in schema.items():
            if isinstance(value, _Settings):
                if isinstance(value, Namespace):
                    if value.__owner is not None:
                        raise ValueError(repr(name) + 'has an owner!')
                    value.__owner = self
                self.__original[name] = value
            else:
                raise TypeError(repr(name) + ' has bad type!')

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        """Set a named Parameter with a given value to be validated."""
        if name in {'_Namespace__original',
                    '_Namespace__dynamic',
                    '_Namespace__static',
                    '_Namespace__owner',
                    'state'}:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
        elif '.' in name:
            head, tail = name.split('.', 1)
            self[head][tail] = value
        else:
            attr = self.__original.get(name)
            if not isinstance(attr, Parameter):
                raise AttributeError(name)
            attr.validate(value)
            if value == attr.value:
                self.__dynamic.pop(name, None)
            else:
                self.__dynamic[name] = value

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Get a Namespace or Parameter value by its original name."""
        if '.' in name:
            head, tail = name.split('.', 1)
            return self[head][tail]
        if name in self.__dynamic:
            return self.__dynamic[name]
        attr = self.__original.get(name)
        if isinstance(attr, Namespace):
            return attr
        if isinstance(attr, Parameter):
            return attr.value
        raise AttributeError(name)

    __setitem__ = __setattr__
    __getitem__ = __getattr__

    def save(self, path):
        """Save the state of the entire Namespace tree structure."""
        if isinstance(self.__owner, Namespace):
            self.__owner.save(path)
        else:
            self._save(path, {Namespace: self.state})

    def load(self, path):
        """Load the state of the entire Namespace tree structure."""
        if isinstance(self.__owner, Namespace):
            self.__owner.load(path)
        else:
            self.state = self._load(path)[Namespace]

    def __get_state(self):
        """Get the state of this Namespace and any child Namespaces."""
        state = {}
        for name, types in self.__static.items():
            box = state.setdefault(name, {})
            for type_, value in types.items():
                box[type_] = value.state if type_ is Namespace else value
        for name, value in self.__original.items():
            box = state.setdefault(name, {})
            if name in self.__dynamic:
                value = self.__dynamic[name]
            elif isinstance(value, Parameter):
                value = value.value
            else:
                box[Namespace] = value.state
                continue
            box.setdefault(Parameter, {})[type(value)] = value
        return state

    def __set_state(self, state):
        """Set the state of this Namespace and any child Namespaces."""
        dispatch = {Namespace: self.__set_namespace,
                    Parameter: self.__set_parameter}
        for name, box in state.items():
            for type_, value in box.items():
                dispatch[type_](name, value)

    def __set_namespace(self, name, state):
        """Set the state of a child Namespace."""
        attr = self.__original.get(name)
        if not isinstance(attr, Namespace):
            attr = self.__static.setdefault(name, {})[Namespace] = Namespace()
        attr.state = state

    def __set_parameter(self, name, state):
        """Set the state of a child Parameter."""
        attr = self.__original.get(name)
        for type_, value in state.items():
            if isinstance(attr, Parameter):
                try:
                    attr.validate(value)
                except TypeError:
                    pass
                else:
                    if value == attr.value:
                        self.__dynamic.pop(name, None)
                    else:
                        self.__dynamic[name] = value
                    continue
            if not isinstance(value, type_):
                raise TypeError(repr(name) + ' has bad type!')
            self.__static.setdefault(name, {}).setdefault(
                Parameter, {})[type_] = value

    state = property(__get_state, __set_state, doc='Namespace state property.')


class Parameter(_Settings):

    """Parameter(value, validator=lambda value: True) -> Parameter instance"""

    def __init__(self, value, validator=lambda value: True):
        """Initialize the Parameter instance with a value to validate."""
        self.__value, self.__validator = value, validator
        self.validate(value)

    def validate(self, value):
        """Check that value has same type and passes validator."""
        if not isinstance(value, type(self.value)):
            raise TypeError('Value has a different type!')
        if not self.__validator(value):
            raise ValueError('Validator failed the value!')

    @property
    def value(self):
        """Parameter value property."""
        return self.__value


###############################################################################


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot!!